# Sql query to display earnings increase or decrease - in percentages

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to write an `sql query` that would display the **earnings** of a **month** compared to another, in **percentages**.

For example I'd need to calculate `sum` of `price` field entries for orders that have been added in **November 2016** (i got a **date** field, `timestamp` type)

then calculate the `sum` of `price` field entries from **December 2016** and so on till today (**January**, **February**, **March**..etc)

then display the comparison results in percentages, let's say for example **December** compared to **November** had a 10% increase in earnings while **January** compared to **December** had an 8% decrease in earnings and so on..my aim is to display these increases between months, in percentages.

Current sql query(not much):

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS Earnings FROM orders WHERE date LIKE '2016-12-%'
```

> Query works and is displaying the sum of price for the Year & Month
>   specified.

How do I move forward from here and do what I mentioned above?

I'd appreciate any pointers!
Please let me know If I've forgot to mention something or haven't been clear with my question, I'll edit.

Using `MysQL`

Table name is `orders`, fields are named `price` (int), `date` (timestamp) and others (id, etc..)

Comment: What's the result if you do `select price FROM orders WHERE date='2016-12'`?

Comment: Try `where date like '2016-12-%'`

Comment: @jarlh Nothing, the query works but doesn't display anything. Adding the like to the where clause works, returned the sum of price. Thanks! Could you expand further?

Comment: The date columns contains year part, month part and day part. You want all rows with a specified year and month, but any day.

Comment: Awesome, working now. I'll edit the question to cut out the date part as this is resolved, thank you. hoping to get the rest done..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return you the sum of the orders grouped by month

```
select  year(date) as year, month(date) as month, sum(price) as total
from    orders
group by year(date), month(date)
```

Displaying the percentage variation between each month and the previous one would require joining the query above with itself, like

```
select  t1.month, t1.year, t1.total, (t1.total / t2.total - 1) * 100 as variation
from    (
            select  year(date) as year, month(date) as month, sum(price) as total
            from    orders
            group by year(date), month(date)
        ) t1
join    (
            select  year(date) as year, month(date) as month, sum(price) as total
            from    orders
            group by year(date), month(date)
        ) t2
on      t2.year = case when t1.month = 1 then t1.year - 1 else t1.year end and
        t2.month = case when t1.month = 1 then 12 else t1.month - 1 end;
```

**Edit**

In your table you only have data for October and December 2016 and February and March of 2017, so the only couple of consecutive months is Feb / Mar; that's why only March is shown.

The increment is big because the monthly sum went from less than 100 to almost 1000, hence that percentage. I fixed the formula though, it should be more precise now.

Btw, you can see the query working with fake data [here](http://rextester.com/EPAM25201)

**Edit 2**

I found a way to make the query work with missing months too. The logic of the join is moved inside a relationship table that links each month to the closest previous one.

```
select  t1.year, t1.month, t1.total, (t1.total / t2.total - 1) * 100 as variation
from    (
            /* month results */
            select  year(date) as year, month(date) as month, sum(price) as total
            from    orders
            group by year(date), month(date)
        ) t1
join    (
            /* relationship between months and previous months */
            select  year(t1.date) * 100 + month(t1.date) t1_calc,
                    max(year(t2.date) * 100 + month(t2.date)) t2_calc
            from    orders t1
            join    orders t2
            on      year(t1.date)*100 + month(t1.date) > year(t2.date)*100 + month(t2.date)
            group by month(t1.date)
        ) rel
on      t1.year * 100 + t1.month = rel.t1_calc
join    (
            /* previous month results */
            select  year(date) as year, month(date) as month, sum(price) as total
            from    orders
            group by year(date), month(date)
        ) t2
on      t2.year * 100 + t2.month = rel.t2_calc;
```

You can see it in action [here](http://rextester.com/LJZFS38315)

Comment: Hello, thank you for the great answer. Both query's work, If I use just your 2nd query code it only shows sum of price for March 2017 and 8906.6667 as variation. I'm confused, shouldn't it show variations between each month available?

Comment: could you please provide some sample data from your orders table? It's probably because of some typos, it's hard to test without data :)

Comment: Sure, added two screenies for you, one is the result of the 2nd code you provided and the other is a screenie of some of the data inside the orders table. Don't worry about price and date being named in another language, I've modified it appropriately so that's not the problem. Link: https://postimg.org/gallery/xwe0oqbm/

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, just realized you could be referring to actual data, not screenies. If that's the case let me know, I'll do an export or set up a pastebin or something :)

Comment: I edited my answer with the explaination of your doubts. Btw, posting images is discouraged because in case links break your content would be less useful for future readers

Comment: You're welcome! I edited my answer with a better solution